# Laravel one-to-one relationship fails

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I created two migrations, because I wanted to create a one-to-one relationship between `Trend` and `TrendExplanation`.

```
Schema::create('trend_explanations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('demographical')->nullable();
    $table->text('economical')->nullable();
    $table->text('social')->nullable();
    $table->text('technological')->nullable();
    $table->text('ecological')->nullable();
    $table->text('political')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is the migration for the `Trend` model:

```
Schema::create('trends', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('explanation_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('explanation_id')->references('id')->on('trend_explanations');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

So in the models I did the following additions:

```
class Trend extends Model
{
    public function explanation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TrendExplanation::class);
    }
}
```

And of course I created a seeder to test it out:

```
$trend = new Trend();
$trend->name = "Something";
$trend->description = "Description";

$explanation = new TrendExplanation();
// ...
$trend->explanation()->save($explanation);
$trend->save();
```

And when I run it, I receive the error: `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'trend_id' in 'field list'`.

How does this happen? I don't understand what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the foreign and local keys when specifying the relationship. It usually goes

```
$this->hasOne(Class, foreign, local);
```

So your definition would be:

```
return $this->hasOne(TrendExplanation::class, 'id', 'explanation_id');
```

Comment: How comes Eloquent doesn't figure that out? Should I have called it `trend_explanation_id`?

Comment: When using hasOne, it expects the foreign key to be a reference of the local key. I think `belongsTo` is the opposite, where the local key would be a reference of the foreign key. [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: Hmm, alright.. I do receive a new error now, saying ```[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                           SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'explanation_id' doesn't have a default value```

Comment: You're trying to set a trend then an explanation. The way you have it, the explanation is the parent of the trend, so the explanation must be saved first.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like the other way around from what I intended. I meant for a `Trend` to have an `TrendExplanation`. How do I turn it around and fix it?

Comment: You'll have to adjust your tables to have the foreign key on the explanations, instead. Then use hasMany explanations inside of the Trends model, and belongsTo inside the Explanations model.